# Corepresentations on Hilbert modules

Tags: reference-request, oa.operator-algebras, hopf-algebras

In the seminal paper ["Unitaires multiplicatifs et dualité pour les produits croisés de $C^*$-algèbres"](http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=ASENS_1993_4_26_4_425_0) by Baaj and Skandalis, we find the following very general definition of what a corepresentation of a Hopf $C^*$-algebra (perhaps more properly called a "$C^*$-bialgebra") is:

[image: Definition 0.3]

There are no references given.  I would justify the definition by using the isomorphism between $\mathcal L(H\otimes A)$ and $M(K(H)\otimes A)$, the latter algebra being where we usually take corepresentations to live.

> I am interested in earlier, or contemporaneous, work which considers such a definition in more detail (or even just gives the definition).

That is, where does this definition come from?  Is this the first paper to make it?